# Add sub-headers in all pages with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a simple script that generates a PDF file. I'm getting the info I need from the database and using a `foreach` to create the pages of the PDF file, and the last page I have some charts and other info that are not retrived from DB. All the pages, except this last one, must have a subheader.

My current code is:

```
foreach ($sql as $key => $value) 
{
    $pdf->Cell(20, $line_height, $value['sale_id'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(90, $line_height, $value['product'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(90, $line_height, $value['ammount'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(90, $line_height, $value['value'], '', '', 'L');
}
```

Basically, I need to have the subheader describing each row. But If I do this, all the lines will have the subheader:

```
foreach ($sql as $key => $value) 
{
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', $font_size);
    $pdf->Ln(2 * $line_height);

    $pdf->Cell(20, $line_height, 'Number', '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(120, $line_height, 'Product', '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, 'Ammount', '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, 'Value ($)', '', '', 'L');

    // 

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', $font_size);
    $pdf->Ln(2 * $line_height);

    $pdf->Cell(20, $line_height, $value['sale_id'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(120, $line_height, $value['product'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, $value['ammount'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, $value['value'], '', '', 'L');
}
```

I need this subheader in each page, except the last one. I've tried to do some crazy code with `pageNo()` function, but it didn't work.

Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I solved my problem. For anyone who's looking for something similar, here is what I did: The `GetY()` function return the Y position of that line, so when it's the first line of the page, this value will be 0 (or a constant, depends of your layout). I just did:

```
foreach ($sql as $key => $value) 
{

    if ($pdf->GetY() == 0)
    {
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', $font_size);
        $pdf->Ln(2 * $line_height);

        $pdf->Cell(20, $line_height, 'Number', '', '', 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(120, $line_height, 'Product', '', '', 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, 'Ammount', '', '', 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, 'Value ($)', '', '', 'L');
    }

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', $font_size);
    $pdf->Ln(2 * $line_height);

    $pdf->Cell(20, $line_height, $value['sale_id'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(120, $line_height, $value['product'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, $value['ammount'], '', '', 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(40, $line_height, $value['value'], '', '', 'L');
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

override the method **header()** of **FPDF** in your class.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    public function Header() {
        $this->Cell(0, 8, "HEADER TEXT", 0, 0, 'R');
    }
}
```

This method will be called ***automatically*** by the FPDF while adding a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem trying to get a header on each page. This also connects to a MySql database. Here is what ended up working for me.

```
<?php
//PDF USING MULTIPLE PAGES
//FILE Originally CREATED BY: Carlos José Vásquez Sáez
//I fixed this on May 3/2013 as it was not working correctly for me.

define('FPDF_FONTPATH', '/font/');
require('fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","","") or die ('Could not select database.');
$db_select = mysql_select_db("", $link) or die ('Could not select database.');


//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new FPDF();

//Open file
$pdf->Open();

//Disable automatic page break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage();

//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 10;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 8;

//print column titles for the actual page
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(80, $row_height, 'Products', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(20, $row_height, 'Price', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(30, $row_height, 'Customer', 1, 0, 'C', 1);

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$result=mysql_query('SELECT Product,Price,Customer FROM your_table ORDER BY Product', $link);

//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 30;

//Data Table y axis position starting point
$y_axis = $y_axis_initial + $row_height;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
    if ($i == $max)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(80, $row_height, 'Product', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(20, $row_height, 'Price', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(30, $row_height, 'Customer', 1, 0, 'C', 1);

        //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
        $i = 0;
    //Reset the y axis value
    $y_axis = $y_axis_initial + $row_height;;
    }

    $Product = $row['Product'];
    $Price = $row['Price'];
    $Cust = $row['Customer'];

    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(80, $row_height, $Product, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20, $row_height, $Price, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, $row_height, $Cust, 1, 0, 'L', 1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = $i + 1;
}

mysql_close($link);

//Create file
$pdf->Output();
```