# FPDF table exceeds right margin

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm editing a code that creates a PDF from a table filled with data called from a DB.

The code works perfectly to print in the columns the data of the parameters named in the first row as you can see in the picture.

[image: Table showed OK]

But when the DB asks for several parameters, the columns exceed the right margin limit.
As you can see in this image.

[image: Table exceeded]

I've seen every post in this web from people having problems with tables and FPDF but I can't find a wayout.

This is the code I have to print the data in the PDF:

```
        $type = 'application/pdf';
        $pdf=new \FPDF('L');//Querformat
        $name=$arbeitsplatz->getName();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->SetTitle('Arbeitsplatzliste');
        $pdf->SetAuthor($user_info->getKuerzel());
        $pdf->SetCreator('PMA Manager');
        $pdf->SetSubject("Arbeitsplatzliste drucken");
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);
        $pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);
        //$pdf->SetTopMargin(20);//in mm
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $cellLength_array=array();

        //set initial Y axis position 
        $y_axis = 20;
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);

        if ($pdf->GetY() == $y_axis)
        {
            //Kopfzeile(Tabelle header)
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,"Probe",1,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(20,7,"Frist",1,0,'L');

            //Start to write table
            foreach($apParamArray as $parameter)
            {
                if($bereich==='W' || $bereich==='I'){
                    $arbeit_para_name=utf8_decode($parameter->getName()).' ['.utf8_decode($parameter->getEinheit()).']';
                }
                else 
                {
                    $arbeit_para_name=utf8_decode($parameter->getNameD()).' ['.utf8_decode($parameter->getEinheit()).']';
                }
                $length=strlen($arbeit_para_name)*2;
                array_push($cellLength_array,$length);
                $pdf->Cell($length,7,$arbeit_para_name,1,0,'C');

            }   
                $pdf->Ln(7);//mm
        }

        //Start to add data
        foreach($apProbenArray as $probe)
        {
            $frist=$probe->getFrist();
            $keys=array();
            $keys=array_keys($probe->getParameterliste());

            if($bereich==='W'  || $bereich==='I'){$pma_nr=$probe->getPmaNr();} else{$pma_nr= $probe->getLaborNr();}
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$pma_nr,'LRB',0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(20,7,$frist,'LRB',0,'L');

            for($j=0;$j<(sizeof($arbeit_para_r_ID_array));$j++)
            {
                $breite=$cellLength_array[$j];
                $arbeit_parameterID=$arbeit_para_r_ID_array[$j];
                if(in_array($arbeit_parameterID , $keys))
                {
                    $parameterliste=$probe->getParameterliste();
                    //print_r($parameterliste);
                    $ergebnis=$parameterliste[$arbeit_parameterID]->getErgebnis();
                    if($ergebnis!==null)
                        $pdf->Cell($breite,7,utf8_decode($ergebnis),'LRB',0,'C');
                    else
                        $pdf->Cell($breite,7,'...','LRB',0,'C');
                }
                else
                    $pdf->Cell($breite,7,'','LRB',0,'C');
            }

            $pdf->Ln(7);//mm
        }   
        //end of writting data

        //Print and get file
        $pdf->Output('prints/Arbeitsplatzliste.pdf','F');
        $fichier='../web/prints/Arbeitsplatzliste.pdf';
        $response = new Response();
        $filename='Arbeitsplatzliste.pdf';
        $response->setContent(file_get_contents($fichier));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $type);
        $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename='.$filename);
        return $response;
```

`

I tryed adding a condition

```
if ($pdf->GetY() == $y_axis) && ($pdf->GetX() == -10)
$pdf->AddPage();
```

But didn't work.

My intention was also to show the header line in all pages, but It doesn't work either.

I tryed with this -> [How to display table header in every page using FPDF library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581064/how-to-display-table-header-in-every-page-using-fpdf-library)

And this -> [Add sub-headers in all pages with FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548083/add-sub-headers-in-all-pages-with-fpdf)

Comment: use MultiCell instead of Cell
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: I think I'm already using MultiCell. Because it breaks line for each new Test to print.
Rows-> Tests    |   
Columns-> Parameters to show/edit

Comment: In the first image it receives 4 parameters, so it prints 4 columns correctly. But in the second image it receives 9 parameters for every test. At the end of the margin it should break page the 5 restant columns (even if the table format will look weird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it finally with this:

```
if($pdf->GetX() < 230)
{
$pdf->Cell($length,7,$parameter,1,0,'C',1);
}
else
$pdf->ln();
```

So when the array of cells reaches the X axis limit (I've selected 230mm because I have the page configurated in Landscape mode), it will break line.

And for showing the header in every page, I tried several times with the Header() function but didn't work.
So I made a condition with GetY() function, then when the GetY() value is equal to the top margin of the new page, it will print the header; if not, it will continue writting the table data.

```
if($pdf->GetY() == 5)
{
$pdf->ln();
//Header...
}
else
{
//Table data...
}
```

I hope this could help someone else.